# How to get some data on a json file?

Tags: python, json

i doing a code for train my level in python and i want to make something with the backpack.tf api (a marketplace for team fortress 2 items):

```
from BackpackTF import *
import json

user = Account(client_id="", 
client_secret="", api_key="")


listings = user.search_Classifieds(intent="buy", page_size=10, fold=1, item_name="Killer Esclusive", 
tradable="1", craftable="1", wear_tier="", quality="6",
                       paint="", particle="", killstreak_tier="", sheen="", killstreaker="", page=0, 
texture_name="")


with open('listings.json', 'w') as outfile:
json.dump(listings, outfile, indent=4)

with open('listings.json', 'r') as outfile:
x = json.load(outfile)
```

and this .json file (a short text):

```
    "buy": {
    "total": 153,
    "listings": [
        {
            "id": "440_76561198305168523_706f2621c0642185d201df6c97d10a4d",
            "steamid": "76561198305168523",
            "item": {
                "defindex": 30609,
                "quality": 6,
                "name": "Taunt: The Killer Solo"
            },
            "appid": 440,
            "currencies": {
                "metal": 49.22
            },
            "offers": 1,
            "buyout": 1,
            "details": "\u2728\ud83d\udc95 Buying for 49.22 ref. Current stock: 1 / 2. Send me a trade offer and it'll be accepted instantly. Type !s Taunt: The Killer Solo in chat and I'll send you a trade offer instead! \u2728\ud83d\udc95",
            "created": 1576328142,
            "bump": 1576328142,
            "intent": 0,
            "automatic": 1
        },
"sell": {
    "total": 276,
    "listings": [
        {
            "id": "440_8303568215",
            "steamid": "76561198358236080",
            "item": {
                "id": 8303568215,
                "original_id": 5964410060,
                "defindex": 538,
                "level": 10,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147485985,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 0,
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "defindex": 746,
                        "value": 1065353216,
                        "float_value": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 292,
                        "value": 1115684864,
                        "float_value": 64
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 388,
                        "value": 1115684864,
                        "float_value": 64
                    }
                ],
                "name": "The Killer Exclusive"
            },
            "appid": 440,
            "currencies": {
                "metal": 1.77
            },
```

i want to get the "metal" in "buy" and the "metal" in "sell". It is possible ? My goal is if the "metal" value is less than the "metal" sell price, i get a print in a log.txt.
Thank's for help (i'm new in python :) )

Comment: can you add all schema of your json file ?

Comment: there is the full json file : https://anonfile.com/V5m858F9n4/listings_json

Comment: The ".json file" you quote above is not valid JSON, which may explain why you can't load it. If it passes a validator, it isn't representative for inclusion in your question. As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask], these should avoid common causes for bad questions like these.

Comment: @AnzoToi  update the code to be at the same time

Comment: okay , ty for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example :

```
import json

with open('listings.json', 'rt') as f:
  nobel = json.load(f)

for i, j in zip(nobel['buy']['listings'], nobel['sell']['listings']):
    print('loop 2 same time')
    print(i['currencies']['metal'])
    print(j['currencies']['metal'])
```

EDIT :  update the code to be at the same time

Comment: I tried and i've got only the firt buy and the first sell price only, it is normal?

Comment: @AnzoToi  that is because your json just have 2 prices in all...49.22 and 1.77 ...if you add print(i['id']) and print(j['id']) you will see differents ID sell or buy